# Want to parse JSON in a bash script, but getting "python: cannot execute binary file" error

Tags: json, python-3.x, bash, parsing

I'm trying to write a shell script where I parse some JSON.  Specifically, I want to extract the value of an "id" element.  I have the below (I have Python 3 installed on my system) ...

```
user_json=$(curl --header "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $json_token" --data "$req" --request POST "$URL/mypath")
echo $user_json
user_id=$(echo $user_json | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print(obj["id"])')
echo $user_id
```

However the above results in a

```
/opt/scripts/sync_script.sh: line 36: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python: cannot execute binary file
```

on the "python" line (the $user_id var is never printed).  What else do I need to do to get this working?  When the $user_json is printed out, I can clearly see the "id" value ...

```
{"id":"4b8d53a5-d0b5-4175-82ec-8aeda435ba62","first_name":"ddd"}
```

**Edit:** In response to comments, I get the below error when attempting to see the version of my Python.  Permissions are included as well.

```
localhost:tmp davea$ /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python -version
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python: cannot execute binary file
localhost:tmp davea$ ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python
-rwxr-xr-x 1 davea admin 2382880 Apr 16  2019 /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python
```

Comment: Do you have permission to run `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python`?

Comment: This isn't really a question about parsing in any meaningful way -- if you can't run your Python interpreter at all, it won't run *at all*; that doesn't depend on what the specific code you're feeding it is.

Comment: @Poshi, this doesn't look like lack of permissions -- that has a different and distinct error. This looks like, maybe, a binary built for a different system architecture (running a 32-bit binary on an OS version that only supports 64-bit, f/e).

Comment: @Poshi, Interestingly, no, I'm not able to run the binary.  I included what happens when I try and list the version as well as the permissions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, good point. But at the end, it boils down to get the interpreter running. The code is OK. Maybe using `file` on the interpreter can shed some light regarding the kind of binary OP have, so he can check if it is a valid one.

Comment: The path to your Python interpreter looks wrong. It normally ends in `.../bin/python3` Where did you get that path?

Comment: If `file` says it's built for the right architecture, I'd then proceed to checking the shared libraries. But this really needs to be a question specifically about getting your Python interpreter (installed by whichever software maintains `/usr/local/Cellar`, on whichever specific OS have) running.

Comment: Why have you started another question.... let's resolve this one first!!! https://stackoverflow.com/q/60550018/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, *I* advised starting another question, because the underlying problem here is very different from the immediate problem, so an answer focused around parsing JSON is unlikely to help someone else with the "cannot execute binary" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using python -m|json.tool utility or jq[.]
In bash i would simply do something like this,

```sh
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $json_token" --data "$req" --request POST "$URL/mypath" | python -m json.tool
```

or

```sh
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $json_token" --data "$req" --request POST "$URL/mypath" |jq [.]
```

And also make sure python is set properly in youe env $PATH

Comment: Put 4 spaces at the start of each line of code to get it formatted correctly.

Comment: `jq [.]` *may* be silently replaced with `jq .` by the shell, depending on how `GLOBIGNORE` and `dotglob` are set. Safer to make it `jq '[.]'` to explicitly tell the shell not to replace it regardless of current configuration.

Comment: I don't have GLOBIGNORE/dotglob set in my SHELL